# Visual Studio 2013 C++: STL container's elements display in debugger

Tags: c++, debugging, visual-studio-2013, data-visualization

MSVS 2013 during C++ debugging (Autos and Watch windows) shows only size of STL container's:

```
MSVS 2010: "[9](9,8,7,6,5,4,3,2,1)"
MSVS 2013: "{ size=9 }"
```

Line expand is required to see element's value in MSVS 2013.
Is there any way to make MSVS 2013 show STL containers like MSVS 2010 in debugger?
I tried to remove **stl.natvis** (it is used in 2013), but it doesn't help: **autoexp.dat** is still not used.
Is possible to force MSVS 2013 use **autoexp.dat**?
Is it possible to modify **stl.natvis** scripts (construct **DisplayString** from container element's values)?
Any other way?

Comment: It seems you can modify the files: http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/Writing-type-visualizers-2eae77a2

Comment: autoexp.dat is no longer used since VS2012. You have to use .natvis files. See the link @user3125562 gave for instructions. Don't forget to save a copy of the original file!

Comment: Yes, the file can be modified, but I could not understand from the article, how to construct **DisplayString** from element's values.

Comment: boost also has its own visualisers, maybe those can be of help? or try looking for other examples. Else explain where you are and what goes wrong.

Comment: @user3125562, i found boost visualizers package (C++ Debugger Visualizers for VS2012/VS2013), but each record inside boost*.natvis files also shows only container size in **DisplayString**. So, the question "how to put all elements values in **DisplayString** in *.natvis?" is still without answer..

Comment: There is a suggestion [here](http://visualstudio.uservoice.com/forums/121579-visual-studio/suggestions/5160933-c-edit-and-continue-in-the-new-debug-engine) at MS that is a way of asking MS to get off their a** and fix the problem.  Vote for it if you want this to be fixed in the next release.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found one way to force MSVS 2012/2013 use autoexp.dat: set "**Enable Edit And Continue**" and "**Enable Native Edit and Continue**".
It disables "data viewing enhancements" (natvis) for C++, and elements of std::vector (std::list, std::map, ...) become displayed on the main line of the variable (MSVS 2010 style).
But, it still would be interesting, is it possible to modify **stl.natvis** to get the same display result?

Comment: IMO natvis is a huge regression (among others in Vs2012/13). The very idea to use xml for things that are full of &, < and > is ridiculous. I guess somebody got XML-poisoned at Microsoft.

Comment: By the way, I hope I'll be able to make my autoexp.dat working using your suggestion, otherwise I'm still sticking with vs2008

Comment: There is a suggestion [here](http://visualstudio.uservoice.com/forums/121579-visual-studio/suggestions/5160933-c-edit-and-continue-in-the-new-debug-engine) at MS that is a way of asking MS to get off their a** and fix the problem.  Vote for it if you want this to be fixed in the next release.

Comment: I tried this with Visual Studio 2013 Community and it didn't work, ie. it didn't use the autoexp.dat file. :-(

Answer (score 7):

As a partial solution you can add multiple conditional `DisplayString` elements to each container type's information in a `.natvis` file.

The limitation to this is that you can specify that elements only up to some fixed maximum be displayed in the `DisplayString` debugger output (however, all elements are still displayed in the expansion area that you get when clicking on the variable's `+` sign in the debugger display).

As an example, drop this into a file named `%USERPROFILE%\My Documents\Visual Studio 2013\Visualizers\custom.stl.natvis`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<AutoVisualizer xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/vstudio/debugger/natvis/2010">

<Type Name="std::vector&lt;*&gt;">
    <DisplayString Condition="(_Mylast - _Myfirst) >  3">[{_Mylast - _Myfirst}] ({_Myfirst[0]}, {_Myfirst[1]}, {_Myfirst[2]}, ...)</DisplayString>
    <DisplayString Condition="(_Mylast - _Myfirst) == 3">[{_Mylast - _Myfirst}] ({_Myfirst[0]}, {_Myfirst[1]}, {_Myfirst[2]})</DisplayString>
    <DisplayString Condition="(_Mylast - _Myfirst) == 2">[{_Mylast - _Myfirst}] ({_Myfirst[0]}, {_Myfirst[1]})</DisplayString>
    <DisplayString Condition="(_Mylast - _Myfirst) == 1">[{_Mylast - _Myfirst}] ({_Myfirst[0]})</DisplayString>
    <DisplayString>{{ size={_Mylast - _Myfirst} }}</DisplayString>
    <Expand>
        <Item Name="[size]">_Mylast - _Myfirst</Item>
        <Item Name="[capacity]">_Myend - _Myfirst</Item>
        <ArrayItems>
            <Size>_Mylast - _Myfirst</Size>
            <ValuePointer>_Myfirst</ValuePointer>
        </ArrayItems>
    </Expand>
</Type>

</AutoVisualizer>
```

And in your next VS2013 C++ debug session vectors will show up to the first three elements in the debugger's `DisplayString` output in a format similar to the old autoexp.dat display.

You can make the obvious additional edits to the custom natvis to display more than 3 elements.  Unfortunately, you'll need to do something similar for each container type you want displayed this way; probably a good job for an intern.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I will use it, if don't find any other way. But three elements is too few, special script will be required to generate custom.stl.natvis capable to display 1..32 elements :)

Comment: I agree that three elements is too few; it was just to demonstrate the idea.  I also agree that doing this for a reasonable number of elements and a reasonable set of containers will be tedious. Fortunately it only needs to be done once, though it'll probably need tweaks/fixes for different versions of VS.

Answer (score 1):

FYI, to use autoexp.dat in VS2015 set "Use Native Compatibility Mode" under

`Options > Debugging > General`

Comment: If the option is grayed out, disable "Enable Edit and Continue".

Answer (score 1):

Uncheck "Show raw structure of objects in variables windows" in `Options > Debugging > General`.