# Possible workaround for Visual Studio 2012/2013 debugger not displaying std::string values

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-studio-2012, clr

I have also posted this on the MSDN forum here: [MSDN Forum Post](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/7930faae-a309-4a18-93ac-1714e739b631/debugger-not-displaying-stdstring-values?forum=vsdebug)

When using the /clr option with a Visual Studio C++ project, the debug visualizer for std::string and other types don't seem to be working.  Here are the steps:

- Launch VS2012 or 2013
- Create a new Visual C++ / Win32 Console Application
- In the main .CPP file, add: `#include <string>`
- In the main method, add: `std::string s = "abc";`
- Debug the program and inspect the variable 's'.  Notice how it shows the string "abc".  This is what we want.
- Open the project properties / General.  Set "Common Language Runtime Support" = "Common Language Runtime Support (/clr)"
- Debug the program and inspect the variable 's'.  Now the string "abc" does not appear.

Further info:

I can see debug visualizer definitions for std::basic_string in both the autoexp.dat and stl.natvis files for Visual Studio.  However it appears to be ignoring these when /clr is used.  One way I'm confirming that it's actually ignoring these definitions is by putting extra text in them. When /clr is not used, VS shows the text in preview; with /clr on, it does not.

There are other similar threads about this such as:

- [Visual Studio 2013 C++: STL container's elements display in debugger](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20819665/visual-studio-2013-c-stl-containers-elements-display-in-debugger)
- Other links in the MSDN post; stackoverflow won't let me post more yet.

However, all of these threads seems to indicate that autoexp.dat and/or natvis files are used and can be modified.  In my case, I believe these files are being completely ignored when /clr is used.

Does anyone know of a work-around?