# How to get the element value of the iterator in Visual Studio immediate window ? *iterator doesn't work

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2012, iterator

***Update***

It seems we can't use the `*iter` to get the value of the element in the iterator.

So is there a easy way to get the value of the *iter* ?

I don't want to type the `iter->xxx._xxx->_xxx` everytime.

I tried to use **AHK** to remap the string, is there a better way ?

---

I use `*iterator` in the immediately window in Visual Studio 2013.
The iterator is defined as `std::vector<std::string>::iterator iter = a.begin()`

And I want to check the value of the string which the `iterator` point to.

But I get the ***error***

> There is no operator * matches the operand

[[image: I update the pic and add some comment]

Why's that ? 
Or how can I get the value of the iterator in a easy way?

Comment: Would it be too much to ask for the piece of code which produces this error in your code?

Comment: try  this `for(const auto& iter : a) std::cout << iter;`

Comment: @TarikNeaj: I suppose it would be.

Comment: @TarikNeaj: The attached image shows the problem.  Just for once, I think an image may be the right way to go here (error text is all in ?Chinese?)

Comment: @MartinBonner yeah it's Chinese, which means `There is no operator * matches the operand`

Comment: @TarikNeaj I can get what I want by type in the first line in the red rectangle,`iter._Ptr->_Bx.Ptr` , it seems to tedious. And I tried `*iter` it failed.

Comment: @SunggukLim it's right, but it can't be used in the immediately window in Visual Studio

Comment: Annoyingly, if I expand the image inline, it becomes much harder to read.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `*` operator is overloaded for iterators in order to give you access to their underlying value, and keep the same semantics as pointers. Pointers can be considered, in some context, as iterators, for example when iterating over a C-style array. That's why you can use C- style arrays in STL algorithms.

The immediate window in visual studio seems to not understand that the `*` operator is overloaded for your iterator type. That's why you get this error.

Comment: So it's there a better way to get the element value in the iterator?

Comment: There is a way to define your own viewers for **watches** and **debug value popups** [in this thread] (http://stackoverflow.com/a/111634/4515566) but I'm not aware that it's working for the **Immediate** window but I guess that's not a problem if you just want to see the value, right?

Answer (score 0):

There's essentially [no solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20819665/visual-studio-2013-c-stl-containers-elements-display-in-debugger), it's one of the areas in which Visual Studio has been stuck in the previous century. There's apparently too much fragile technology, and trying to fix one bit of Visual Studio (edit&continue) breaks another (debugger visualization)