# visual studio 2013 debugger vector value error

Tags: c++, debugging, vector, visual-studio-2013

I am currently run a C++ project on VS 2013 update 4 on Windows 8.1. However, when I was debugging, the value of my vector did not show on the debugger window. Instead, it shows me a "{...}". Usually, debugger shows me the value in the vector. But the other variable's value is fine, such as int type of something.

Any help would be appreciated.

Below are the code and the debugger snapshot.

Code

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

int main()
{

    vector<int> test{ 1, 2, 3 };

    test.push_back(3);


    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Debugger:

[image: debug]

Expanded Debugger:
[image]

Updated 2016/09/10

I tried to reset all settings and it works.
However, I still don't know the reason of such problems.

Comment: Post code as text in your question not as image link please.

Comment: I have done that. Sorry for the debugger image. I don't have 10 reputation.

Comment: And what do you see if you click to expand the vector variable?

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ  I have done that. Sorry for the debugger snapshot. I don't have 10 reputation.

Comment: Try to use the vector elements...as I am afraid the initialization could be optimized away by compiler because of no usage

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ I uploaded an expanded debugger image

Comment: @SauravSahu   I tried to output the vector, it did output the elements in the vector. But still, the debugger shows {...} rather than actual value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suspect you are not using the "step-over" when debugging. I think once the program reaches the breakpoint you simply continue (F5). Put the breakpoint and once the program enters the debugger use the "step-over" (F10) to step through the remainder of your code.

[image: Debugger screenshot]

Comment: Thanks for the reply. But I didn't have the chance to do that since I reset all the settings.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that your MSVC Debug Visualizers for STL are bugged or not loaded.

Try running Native Only or this solution https://stackoverflow.com/a/20834982/4990069